# command line arguments in bash to Rscript

Tags: bash, r, arguments

I have a bash script that creates a csv file and an R file that creates graphs from that.

At the end of the bash script I call `Rscript Graphs.R 10`

The response I get is as follows:

```
Error in is.vector(X) : subscript out of bounds
Calls: print ... <Anonymous> -> lapply -> FUN -> lapply -> is.vector
Execution halted
```

The first few lines of my Graphs.R are:

```
#!/bin/Rscript
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
CorrAns = args[1]
```

No idea what I am doing wrong? The advice on the net appears to me to say that this should work. Its very hard to make sense of `commandArgs`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With the following in args.R

```
print(commandArgs(TRUE)[1])
```

and the following in args.sh

```
Rscript args.R 10
```

I get the following output from `bash args.sh`

```
[1] "10"
```

and no error. If necessary, convert to a numberic type using `as.numeric(commandArgs(TRUE)[1])`.

Comment: Thanks. I have discovered it returns as a string. How do I convert that into numeric value. Am just trying to find the answer to that.

Comment: @samar `print(as.numeric(commandArgs(TRUE)[1]))` prints `[1] 10`.

Comment: Just found the answer.  x <- (commandArgs(TRUE)[1]) and then  CorrAns <- eval (parse(text=x))

Comment: @samar Great! Can you post it as an answer in case someone else comes here with the same question?

Comment: sorry I did not see your simpler answer. Am trying to see how to post this as an answer. Any advice on that.

Comment: @samar I'd be very cautious using `eval`. Does `as.numeric()` not work for you? If you need to use `eval`, post it as an answer in the text box labelled "Your Answer" at the end of this page. Then accept the best answer by clicking the tick to the top-right of the answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question and the comments provide the same solution as my answer.

Comment: @Joshua I agree that OP should mark your answer as accepted (I've upvoted it), but does that really warrant a downvote? I wouldn't say my answer is "not useful", as OP didn't provide enough context: there was no indication he wanted an integer answer.

Comment: @marcog I didn't down-vote your answer because I didn't get the best answer.  I down-voted your answer because it simply states that you couldn't replicate the OP's error, which is not particularly helpful (especially as the best answer).  Edit your answer to actually answer the question--so it will be helpful to others--and I will remove my down-vote.  There was enough context that I was able to correctly identify the problem and suggest the solution that you and the OP arrived at independently.

Comment: @Joshua I've edited it in. Please read [When should I vote down?](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/vote-down). And no, you clearly said you guessed. Anyway, I have no intention to debate this further.

Comment: @marcog, You're right.  I forgot that I could have just edited your answer myself.

Answer (score 6):

Just a guess, perhaps you need to convert `CorrAns` from character to numeric, since Value section of `?CommandArgs` says:

> A character vector containing the name
>   of the executable and the
>   user-supplied command line arguments.

UPDATE: It could be as easy as:

```
#!/bin/Rscript
args <- commandArgs(TRUE)
(CorrAns = args[1])
(CorrAns = as.numeric(args[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks. Not quite sure how to implement that. I did not think variable names in R were linked to either character or numeric. However will check through the R Intro book again.

Comment: @samar I would suggest trying `as.numeric(args[1])` as I did in my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is a new site for me just as R is a new experience fo me. Both provide great satisfaction.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [docs](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/commandArgs.html), it seems you might need to remove the `TRUE` from the call to `commandArgs()` as you don't call the script with `--args`. Either that, or you need to call `Rscript Graphs.R --args 10`.

> Usage
>
> `commandArgs(trailingOnly = FALSE)`
>
> Arguments
>
> `trailingOnly`     logical. Should only
>   arguments after `--args` be returned?

Comment: Thanks. I did this but the error message is identical to what I first reported

Comment: @samar See my new answer and see if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

`Rscript args.R 10` where 10 is the numeric value we want to pass to the R script.

`print(as.numeric(commandArgs(TRUE)[1])` prints out the value which can then be assigned to a variable.

Comment: This is the same as my updated answer, and the answer you accepted as "best" doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Joshua, as far as I know I adapted marcog's answer to fit my needs and then entered it as the "best" answer. I do not recollect that your latest answer was visible at that time. However, I do appreciate the assistance.